# AWS - awslogs-agent-setup.py is not supported for Python 3.6

Tags: docker, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

Can someone know how to setup awslog agent so my containerized service can route the log to cloud watch as awslogs-agent-setup.py is not supporting python 3.6. We do not want to have multiple version of Python as there lot application built on python 3.6

Answer (score 6):

You should probably install the [new CloudWatch Agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/install-CloudWatch-Agent-on-first-instance.html) instead of the old python-based awslogs agent. The new agent supports [all the features](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch-Agent-Configuration-File-Details.html#CloudWatch-Agent-Configuration-File-Logssection) of the old agent, is much faster, is a standalone binary without any dependencies, and has [a simple wizard](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/create-cloudwatch-agent-configuration-file-wizard.html) to convert your awslogs config file to the new format.

On the other hand, if you're using docker, you could also use the [native docker driver for CloudWatch Logs](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/awslogs/).

Comment: Your first link redirects to a page where I don't see anything on cloudwatch agent.

Comment: I guess Daniel mentioned the SSM integrated cloudwatch agent. Here is the link: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/12/amazon-cloudwatch-introduces-a-new-cloudwatch-agent-with-aws-systems-manager-integration-for-unified-metrics-and-logs-collection/